# AzerothCore Docker on Windows: '\r': command not found

Tags: windows, bash, docker, azerothcore

Getting this error while trying to run [AzerothCore using Docker](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker) on Windows:

```
Step 9/15 : RUN ./azerothcore/bin/acore-db-asm 1
 ---> Running in 17cc370dcab8
/azerothcore/apps/db_assembler/includes/../../bash_shared/includes.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
ERROR: Service 'ac-database' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c ./azerothcore/bin/acore-db-asm 1' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

[image: AzerothCore error Docker on Windows]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is having a file saved using an `End of line sequence` different than `LF` (the Unix format).

So to solve the problem, open the file that gives error (e.g. `.../bash_shared/include.sh`) with an editor and make sure it's correctly saved using `LF` (because `CRLF` or other formats will break it).

For example, using Visual Studio Code, open the file and then change the format to LF:

[image: vscode change CRLF to LF]

[image: vscode save LF]

select `LF` and save. This should solve the problem.

For Visual Studio, read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks?view=vs-2019